# Проверка возраста "от и до" в выпадающем списке

Tags: jquery

Добрый день.

Есть два выпадающих списка с цифрами от 18 до 90 - "возраст от"  и "возраст до" для фильтра.

Как сделать, чтоб запретить выбирать "возраст от" больше "возраста до" и, наоборот, "возраст до" не должен быть меньше "возраста от".

Как скрывать ненужные цифры?

Спасибо.

Comment: @Роман Ракзин, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Я бы присвоил им каждому ID, если это возможно, навесился на обработчик change для обоих конролов и, проверяя их значения, блокировал бы другие option.

http://jsfiddle.net/mmL5m2me/

Answer (score 1):

Если на скорую руку, то я бы [сделал как-то так](http://jsfiddle.net/kzL4erkt/1/):

```
var ageRange = $('.age_range');
ageRange.on('change', function(){
    var $that = $(this),
        id = this.id,
        $other = ageRange.not($that),
        method = (id == 'from' ? 'prevAll' : 'nextAll'),
        indx = $that.prop('selectedIndex');
    $('option', $other).prop('disabled', false);
    $('option:eq(' + (indx + (id == 'from' ? 1 : -1)) + ')', $other)
    .prop('selected', true)
    [method]()
    .prop('disabled', true);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Как-то так наверное:

```
$('#from').on('change', 
  function() {
      var val = new Number($('#from :selected').text());
      var found = false;     
      $('#to option').each(
          function(index, item) {
              if($(item).text() < val) {
                  $(item).attr('disabled', true);
              }
              else {
                  $(item).removeAttr('disabled');
                  if(!found) {
                      found = true;
                      if(new Number($('#to :selected').text()) < $(item).text())
                          $('#to option:eq(' + index + ')').prop('selected', true);                      
                  }
              }
          });      
  })
```

[Пример](http://jsfiddle.net/esxd1n6v/). Для второго селекта - по аналогии